# Cocos2d-x 4.0 Lens3D and Waves3D Animations

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

I used below code to make water like animation for background image

```
    auto background = Sprite::create(TEX_MM_BG);
    background->setPosition(Vec2(SW*0.5f, SH*0.5f));

    auto nodeGrid = NodeGrid::create();
    nodeGrid->addChild(background);
    this->addChild(nodeGrid, 0);


    ActionInterval* lens = Lens3D::create(10, Size(32, 24), Vec2(100, 180), 150);
    ActionInterval* waves = Waves3D::create(10, Size(15, 10), 18, 15);

    nodeGrid->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Sequence::create(waves,lens, NULL)));
```

Animation look is good. But it stops 10 seconds then play 10 seconds then again stops 10 seconds...it repeats. How to avoid stoping in middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't stop it is applying waves effect followed by lens effect. While applying lens effect the animation of waves stops.

Correct way to code this will be to use a Spawn:

```
 ActionInterval* lens = Lens3D::create(10, Size(32, 24), Vec2(100, 180), 150);
 ActionInterval* waves = Waves3D::create(10, Size(15, 10), 18, 15);
 // Spawn will run both effects at the same time.
 auto lensWaveSpawn = Spawn::createWithTwoActions(lens, waves);

 auto seq = Sequence::create(lensWaveSpawn, nullptr);
 nodeGrid->runAction(RepeatForever::create(seq));
```